# Excel - lowest IP address by octets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking to go through a list of hostnames, mac addresses and IP's and find the lowest IP per Hostname.  I'm trying to find the lowest number in Octet 2, 3 and 4.

I couldn't figure out how to nicely add a table to Stack so I'm using Fiddle and pictures instead.

The large table represents the data and the small table represents the result.

To get the result table, I was going to grab all the hostnames out of the large table and remove duplicates then add formulas to get the "lowest" IP based on the last three octets.

I'm running formulas on the large table to divide out the octets but this may not be needed.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, forgot the table.  https://jsfiddle.net/cuy0zs0b/2/

Comment: Is octet 2 the only one that you care about? In both host examples, you've selected the IP with the lowest value for the second octet, but yet these IPs have values that are greater than other IPs in octet 3 or 4. I guess what I'm asking is: how are you defining "lowest" IP?

Answer (score 1):

I would start with a single helper column with this formula:

```
=--(TEXT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(C2,".",REPT(" ",999)),999,999)),"000")&TEXT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(C2,".",REPT(" ",999)),999*2,999)),"000")&TEXT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(C2,".",REPT(" ",999)),999*3,999)),"000"))
```

It will take the last tree octets and make a number:

[image]

The it is a matter of two equations to get the data:

First lets get the correct IP address.  To do so we use this array formula:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$6,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(($D$2:$D$6 = MIN(IF($A$2:$A$6=A9,$D$2:$D$6))),),0))
```

Being an array it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of just Enter when exiting Edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

The second formula gets the correct MAC Address:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$6,MATCH(C9,$C$2:$C$6,0))
```

It is a simple formula entered regularly.

[image]

Comment: You are a Genius. Highly appreciate your grasp on fundamental concepts.